# Calculating $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor}}$

Tags: limits, ceiling-and-floor-functions

My question is about the following limit:

$$\large\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor}}$$

Where the notation $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is the floor function.
I've graphed it and it is 1 everywhere except for $[0, 1)$.
So, I think the answer should be 1, according to the epsilon-delta definition, since the function isn't defined for $0^+$, we can only check at $0^-$.

Is this correct?
Also, is it to correct to simply cancel both the numerator and denominator here?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the limit is $1$ by the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition. You can cancel the numerator and denominator since they are equal and never $0$ in the domain of the function $x\mapsto\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$. But remember that this function is not the constant function $x\mapsto1$ and don't confuse it with $x\mapsto1$

Comment: Yes you are right, here the limits to $0$ and $0^-$ coincide. The fact that the limit to $0^+$ is undefined doesn't matter.

Comment: You may simplify num/denom, provided you restrict the domain of definition.

Comment: If you are addressing me, I did answer that.

Comment: The function is not defined for $0 <x<1$ so the question does not make sense.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That depends on conventions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on how you define limits. If you *require* that a function is defined on a whole punctured neighborhood of $x_0$ (where you take the limit at), then this function doesn't have a limit at $0$.

If your definition is

> Let $f$ be defined on a set $D$ and let $x_0$ be an accumulation point of $D$ ($x_0$ is not required to belong to $D$). We say that
>   $$
> \lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)=l
> $$
>   if, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>   $$\text{for all $x\in D$, if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$}$$

then you can state correctly that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=1
$$

*Note 1.* The condition that $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D$ avoids problems with isolated points of the domain, so as to ensure uniqueness of the limit.

*Note 2.* With this definition, the limit from the right is *the* limit of the function $f$ *restricted to the domain* $D\cap(x_0,\infty)$. Similarly for the limit from the left.

Comment: $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D-\{x_0\}$ is a redundancy. $x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D\iff x_0$ is an accumulation point of $D-\{x_0\}$, since accumulation points of sets aren't required to be in them

Comment: @ShubhamJohri You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the function is defined only for $x<0$ and, according to the more general definition of limit, we have that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor}}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}{\frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor}}=\lim_{x \to 0^-}1=1$$

For the different definition of limits refer also to the related

- [Does this limit exist on $\mathbb R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3029783/505767)