# Does $\lim_{x \to 1}\left(\frac{x}{[x]}\right)$ exist?

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Does the limit $\lim_{x \to 1}\left(\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}\right)$ exist? Where $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the Greatest Integer Function or the Floor function.

My teacher defined that a limit exists when the Left-hand Limit = Right-Hand Limit and If any one is undefined but the other is finite then also the limit exists. Like $\lim_{x \to 0}\sqrt{x}$ does exist although the LHL does not lie in the domain.

In this question the domain of the function $\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ is $\mathbb R\setminus[0,1)$ where $\mathbb R$ represents Real Numbers. So, The Left-Hand Limit is not defined and Right Hand Limit is $1$, which is finite so according to my teacher Limit does exist. But when I tried this question in WolframAlpha, it is saying that the LHL is $-\infty$ and RHL is $1$, so limit does not exist.

So, a more general question is: do we have to consider the domain of a function when we calculate a limit?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: An example of a limit that is not defined in the reals is $\lim_{x\to-1}\sqrt{x}$ is undefined in the reals, as for any $\epsilon$ that you choose that is less than $1$, $\sqrt{-1+\epsilon}$ and $\sqrt{-1-\epsilon}$ are undefined. But on the other hand, the right-hand limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sqrt{x}$ is defined, as $\sqrt{0+\epsilon}$ is still defined for arbitrarily small positive $\epsilon$.

Comment: @C7X So $\lim_{x \to 0^+}(\sqrt{x})$ does exist but $\lim_{x \to 0}(\sqrt{x})$ does not as it is not in domain?

Comment: It could be rephrased as the continuity of sgn(x) at 1

Comment: @Temp I think I have gotten the $\epsilon$-$\delta$-definition wrong, sorry...

Comment: @C7X My question has been answered that we have to consider the domain. Thanks for the effort

Comment: I didn't see anyone mentioning it but Wolfram Alpha is definitely wrong, whatever definition of limit one consider: saying that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}=-\infty$ means that $\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ is large negative when $x$ is close to $1$. But, as you mentioned, $\frac{x}{\lfloor x\rfloor}$ is undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your teacher is completely right, according to the more general definition of limit, we consider $x$ in the domain and therefore

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\left(\frac{x}{[x]}\right)= \lim_{x \to 1^+}\left(\frac{x}{[x]}\right)=1$$

Refer also to the related

- [Calculating $\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{ \lfloor x \rfloor}{\lfloor x \rfloor}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3043739/505767)
- [What is $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)}{\sin \left(\frac 1 x\right)}$ ? Does it exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889055/505767)

Comment: Ok. So This means that we have to consider the domain for calculating the limit. Thanks

Comment: Yes, we are taking $x\in D\setminus\{1\}$

Comment: It has to be VERY clear from the context, otherwise it is abuse of notation. I think it would be preferable to always write $\lim\limits_{\underset{\Large{x\in\mathcal D}}{x\to 1}}f(x)$

Comment: @zwim I'm also thinking for example to $\lim_{x \to 0} x \log x$, for which we are implicitely assuming $x>0$ but it is not usually indicated as a right side limit. Also in the most autorative textbooks the definition of limit implies that $x$ is in the domain. We have discussed in detail this issue other times. Anyway in case of doubt, the notation you are proposing is a good notation.

Comment: @zwim This is a very complete reference for this kind of discussion https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889055. I've incorporated it in the aswer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all to solve this question of limit first of all you have to be familiar with the definition of limit.

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ will exist only when both the left hand and right hand limits will exist. That is $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ will exist only when $$\lim_{x\to a^{+}}f(x)$$ and $$\lim_{x\to a^{-}}f(x)$$ both will exist.

Now according to your question $$\lim_{x\to 1}(\frac{x}{[x]})$$ will exist only when $$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}}(\frac{x}{[x]})$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}(\frac{x}{[x]})$$ both will exist. Now the interesting fact is that $$\lim_{x\to 1^{+}} [x] = 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}} [x] = 0$$. So, as far as I can guess $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}(\frac{x}{[x]})$$ will be undefined. Therefore since $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}(\frac{x}{[x]})$$ is undefined so, $$\lim_{x\to 1}(\frac{x}{[x]})$$ will not exist.

Though I am not sure whether my logic is correct or not. But I would suggest to verify once.

Comment: this column presentation is not very appealing, can you consider something less chopped.

Comment: You can edit my answer and write it in a good manner@zwim