# Find the domain of the following function $ f(x)={(\ln x)}^{\ln^{2}x} $.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that $ x \gt 0 $ because of logarithm precondition, and I can see that $ x \neq 1 $ because otherwise it would lead to $ 0^0$ which is problematic, but when I checked the graph of the function I have discovered that it started from $ 1 $ on $ x $ axis and $ (0,1) $ interval is not considered.

In sum, I thought that the domain should have been $ (0, \infty) - \{1\}$ but it seems to be $(1,\infty)$ and I can't figure out where I am wrong.

Comment: If $a<0$ then $a^b$ can also be "problematic"...

Comment: the function $f(x) = a^x$ is defined if $a > 0$ then $\ln x$ must be $>0$..

Comment: You cannot take real power of a négative number

Comment: @Lelouch: Well, you *can*, it just requires the use of complex numbers, and doesn't necessarily have a unique value.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>**Note:** this question has only been addressed at the high school level.  Therefore, the given answer does not address the question from a mathematician's point of view.</sup>

---

What I want to do in this answer is to find the *largest interval*, such that for all values ​​in this interval the function $f(x)=(\ln x)^{\ln^2 x}$ is well-defined/meaningful.

By definition we have $0<x\neq 1$.

$$\operatorname{dom}\left[(\ln x)^{\ln^2 x}\right]\longmapsto \ln x>0\vee \left\{\ln x<0\wedge \ln^2x\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

and

$$\ln x>0\implies x>1$$

Then note that, if $\ln x<0$ then, $\ln ^2x \in\mathbb Z$.

Thus,

$$\ln x=-\sqrt n\implies x=e^{-\sqrt n},\, n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}.$$

With all this in mind, we can conclude that,

$$
\begin{aligned}&\operatorname{dom}\left[(\ln x)^{\ln^2 x}\right]\\
=&\left\{x\mid x>1\vee x=e^{-\sqrt n}, \,n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\right\}
\end{aligned}
$$

If you assume $0^0=1$, then $x=1$ is included in the domain:

$$
\begin{aligned}&\operatorname{dom}\left[(\ln x)^{\ln^2 x}\right]\\
=&\left\{x\mid x\ge1\vee x=e^{-\sqrt n}, \,n\in\mathbb Z_{>0}\right\}\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Is the first $\land$ in your first line supposed to be $\lor$?

Comment: @user170231  I confused a bit... I must use "or" instead of "and"?

Comment: I believe so.
$$\ln x>0\wedge \left\{\ln x<0\wedge \ln^2x\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$
sounds contradictory to me - how can both $\ln(x)>0$ *and* $\ln(x)<0$ and $\ln^2(x)\in\Bbb Z$? I think you meant to say
$$\ln x>0\vee \left\{\ln x<0\wedge \ln^2x\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: @user170231 Thank you for reporting this mistake. Now, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we can see that $f(e^{-1}) = {(\ln e^{-1})}^{\ln^{2}e^{-1}} = -1$ so we can see that it is indeed defined for **some** values of $x < 1$ but $f(e^{-1/2})$ is undefined for example.

If you think about it, this question is very similar to asking for the domain of $x^x$ so [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1551492/1078773) might help you. Furthermore, as @David said on his comment, if $a < 0$ then $a^b$ is "problematic". Knowing this, to avoid any problems we would want $\ln x > 0 \implies x > 1$ so we could just conveniently define $\text{dom} f(x) = (1,+\infty)$. And in this case:

$$f(x) = {(\ln x)}^{\ln^{2}x} = (e^{\ln(\ln x)})^{\ln^2 x} = e^{\ln(\ln x) \cdot \ln^2 x}$$

Now let's try to find a larger domain that includes some $x < 1$, to avoid raising numbers to an irrational exponent that is [another problem on its own](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/can-you-raise-a-number-to-an-irrational-exponent), let's consider all rational $\ln x < 0$, then for some $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$, $0 <x = e^{p/q} < 1$ and thus $$f(x) = f(e^{p/q}) = (p/q)^{(p/q)^2} = \sqrt[q^2]{(p/q)^{p^2}}$$ remember that $p/q < 0$ so for this expression to be properly defined we want $p$ to be even **or** $q$ to be odd.

So we can as well **define** the domain of $f(x)$ as $(1,+\infty) \cup \{\ e^{p/q} \in (0,1) \mid p = 2k \text{ or } q = 2k + 1 \text{ for some } k\in\mathbb{Z} \}$.

So its domain really depends on what you define it to be.

Comment: Consider $f(x)=x$, then write $f(x)=e^{\ln x}$. Does this imply $\text{dom} f(x)=(0,+\infty)$?

Comment: @nonstudent You are right, just fixed the answer.